# How to disable EMR Spark runtime eager executor loading

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-emr, eager-loading

AWS introduced Spark runtime and it provides lots of optimization out of the box. One of the optimization it does to eager executor allocation, which allocated max executors as mentioned in `spark.dynamicAllocation.maxExecutors`, which has a default value at app level. It is causing the problem as it also allocating executors for all small jobs as well, where it is not required.

I am looking for the configurations in AWS-EMR 5.3 to disable this eager executor allocation and fallback to the default executor allocation strategy.

Comment: spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled to false

Comment: @thebluephantom I just want to disable eager allocation optimization from the new EMR runtime and don't want to disable dynamicAllocation completely.